Query Designer - SSRS Report - Restrict Parameters by Other Parameters
We have a report in SSRS build using query designer that lives on top of data that comes from the data warehouse. The set up looks like this.
How do I restrict one column by another column. Only return orders dates for performances selected rather then the entire data set available for 20+ years.

I can't select values in the dropdown because those are a list of hard coded values. I want to code it by previous variable/column.
Any thoughts are appreciated.
I should add that because the dataset is a data warehouse - cube, when I add a new dataset it doesn't allow me to type I have to use query designer to create additional datasets and i still don't know how to link the two.

A dependent cascading parameter is generally bound to a query that uses the parent parameter value as input. That way, when the parent changes the child will also reset.

@RossBush is there a way to implement it without creating a new query but rather using this existing one.

You have to use cascading parameters, how do you expect your users to able to edit the query? There is a good article here https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4758/add-cascading-parameters-in-a-ssrs-report-using-mdx-and-ssas-multidimensional/ which might help.

@AlanSchofield thank you for the link, it was/is helpful however i can't figure out how to link my two parameters - there is no way to add a code snippet to this and I'm not sure where i can say only pull order dates for a given season (specified)
